# Arduino wireless and Node.js

Tags: node.js, arduino, serial-port, usb, radio-transmission

I'm working on an Arduino project to control motors and read sensors. I decided to use the web view using [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) as a medium channel to read/write from the serial port to the browser using either libraries (SerialPort and SerialPort2).

Both are working fine when I connect the Arduino directly to the USB device using a wire, but Node.js can't seem to read anything when I connect the Arduino to the USB device through my wireless adapter** ([APC220](http://www.dfrobot.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=57)) even though I can read everything received on it using the Arduino serial monitor.

I checked every possible reason behind that; I checked the baud-rate I'm using for the Arduino communication with the wirelss serial and the APC220 and the bridge connector (USB-to-serial converter). They all have the same settings: 9600 baud-rate, no parity /flowcontrol, data bits: 8 , stop bits: 1.

The behavior is as follows. It connects to the [COM port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_%28hardware_interface%29) without trouble, and then I tried printing the errors, but it seems there are none identified by either SerialPort libraries. Then no reading comes to the event (data), which means it (Node.js) is not interacting with the serialport even though it is open.

Note:
I know I can use another Arduino as a medium between the USB port and the wireless adapter, but I want to understand this problem and solve it cleanly without such work around.

What could the problem be?

server [node.js]:

```
var SerialPort  = require('serialport2').SerialPort;
var portName = 'COM15';

var io = require('socket.io').listen(8000); // Server listens for socket.io communication at port 8000
io.set('log level', 1); // Disables debugging. This is optional. You may remove it if desired.

var sp = new SerialPort(); // Instantiate the serial port.
sp.open(portName, { // portName is instatiated to be COM3, replace as necessary
   baudRate: 9600, // This is synchronised to what was set for the Arduino code
   dataBits: 8, // This is the default for Arduino serial communication
   parity: 'none', // This is the default for Arduino serial communication
   stopBits: 1, // This is the default for Arduino serial communication
   flowControl: false // This is the default for Arduino serial communication
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    // If socket.io receives message from the client browser then
    // this call back will be executed.
    socket.on('message', function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    });
    // If a web browser disconnects from Socket.IO then this callback is called.
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('disconnected');
    });
});

var cleanData = ''; // This stores the clean data
var readData = '';  // This stores the buffer
sp.on('data', function (data) { // Call back when data is received
    readData = data.toString(); // Append data to buffer.
    // If the letters '[' and ']' are found on the buffer then isolate what's in the middle
    // as clean data. Then clear the buffer.
    console.log(readData); // **Here you should be able to print the data if you receive any**
     if (readData.indexOf(']') >= 0 && readData.indexOf('[') >= 0) {
        cleanData = readData.substring(readData.indexOf('[') + 1, readData.indexOf(']'));
        readData = '';
        console.log("-- "+cleanData);
        io.sockets.emit('message', cleanData);
     }else if(readData.indexOf('[') >= 0){
        cleanData = readData.substring(readData.indexOf('[') + 1, readData.length);
        readData = '';
     }else if(readData.indexOf(']') >= 0){
        cleanData += readData.substring(0, readData.indexOf(']'));
        readData = '';
        console.log("-- "+cleanData);
        io.sockets.emit('message', cleanData);
     }else{
        cleanData += readData;
        readData = '';
     }
    //console.log(readData);
    //io.sockets.emit('message', readData);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

While the monitor is running no other program can read the serial port.

In case you do not open both at the same time then things are more tricky. My suggestion would be to spy on the wire. That is: install [Wireshark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) and have a look at the data on the serial connection / USB bus.

You might also want to check how the serial port of the APC220 and the Arduino differ with regard to their serial/USB converters. Another idea would be to analyze this issue under Linux since may allow more insights into the low-level differences of the chip sets / USB activity. Of course if you do not have Linux experience this is hard to do, but maybe you know some Linux enthusiasts.

Comment: I'm not using the serial monitor at the same time with the server, I know it will cause a clash (occupied/used by other app .. ).

that is a good idea, I'll try to analyze the packets with some detailed serial port reader soon.

but I already checked the converter's settings, they are fine. In fact since it is working on the serial monitor and java's serial reader (I used it in another java project), that means the problem resides in the serial port library in node js. Maybe a little manipulation will be needed depending on the analysis results.

Thanks,

Comment: given what you said in your comment, you should give the code you wrote in javascript to open the serial port for us to help you on that part. What library did you use, how do you open the serial line? Do you do the correct termios settings? did you try to make the simplest program possible to send a "Hello world" from arduino to host and back?

Comment: @zmo Code added, but I believe that would make my question look way complicated when it is not; there is nothing wrong with the code as it works over the wire but when I use wireless it works on any serialport reader e.g.(java, arduino .. ) other than node js serialport library .. if I have to go through it that will be the bruteforce solution and that will take me time. that's why I posted the question.

Answer (score -1):

Well, both your codes look all right, so I'm pretty sure your problem is something obvious (like the nose in the middle of your face) that you don't see because you're too focused on details. So here's a checklist I'd do first:

- Are you **sure** your serial interface is the `COM15`, and never changes?
- Are you sure both `APC` devices have correct baudrate configured?
- Did you try making your Arduino send a simple code that sends the same thing over the channel?

Like:

```
void loop() {
  ...println("TEST");
  delay(1000);
}
```

And on your host:

```
sp.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(data.toString());
});
```

When you get something buggy in your system, try to build the most simple use case of that buggy part, so you're sure that's nothing else in your codes that interferes with that. You don't need to make your Arduino work on the GPS stuff, as well as your Node.js stuff work on the web stuff.

Just make it the most simple as you can. (And don't forget to add a delay in your Arduino loop, or you may have difficulties reflashing the chip).

You may also want to add to your code the error catching part of `serialport2`:

```
port.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log("ERROR receiving serial data: ", err);
});
```

As well as for your `open()` statement:

```
sp.open(portName, portConfig, function (err) {
    console.log("ERROR opening serial port: ", err);
});
```

As you may be missing error reporting on the host side!

Comment: I did every thing you just thought of and more before you even mentioned it. I am a developer and I know what I'm doing. I happened to have said all that in the question, maybe an obvious obstacle blocked your sight from all that ?!

Comment: of course, I'm not judging your abilities, but as any other developer you may have missed something that may be really obvious! Especially with arduino based projects, I don't count how many times I checked everything **except** that little stupid thing getting me crazy.

Comment: I've read again (and twice) all you wrote, and it appears clearly that you've done everything I would have done and that can possibly done at your debugging stage (without bringing in a logic analyzer - which can be another arduino device, to see if things are *actually* coming between the wireless device and the FTDI chip, or taking the wireshark...).

Comment: Now, I've had issues working with RF based wireless dongles in the past, where I had regressions working on the code that made non sense. The only solutions I had at those times is to rewrite new minimal codes from scratch that just **works**, and then try to rebuild the software system around that, trying to avoid those regression situations. Did you ever make it to work the way you want with a minimal setup? (you did not tell if you've tried to go this way - my third point in my answer).

Comment: I would have taken this way into consideration if the thing wasn't working at all but it does,, I close the port from node.js then open it using arduino serial monitor, I can see the values printing over RF! ,, that's the strange thing. then I checked the programming of the APC220 using RF - Magic, all the serial settings were right, I also checked the settings of the bridge (Usb to Serial) converter from the port's settings, and the settings turned to be the same. I can't think of something else to be the reason of this other than the serialport library itself.

Comment: keep in mind, I used the same hardware and method with a java project in the past and I faced nothing like this.

Comment: Although I'm doubting the serialport library, but that also doesn't seem logical as it works over the wired connection .. I tried flowcontrol ,, nothing. maybe I used it the wrong way because I never had to use it before!

Comment: well, from what you say, that's the JS library who has a problem communicating with the APC220. Maybe does it ignore a setup parameter that makes it work wired to an arduino but not with the FTDI, or any kind of weird bug like that... I think you're good to read, add printouts and debug node's serial library...

Comment: then there is no other choice but the hard way .. thank you very much for your concern and initiative to help .. even though you claimed that my nose is as big as yours :P, no hard feelings.

Comment: if only you knew how big my nose is :-)

Comment: hehe, you have a picture there .. I can see it :P

Comment: I'm turning my back on that picture! :-) btw, I think that if we continue "chatting" in comments, moderators will rant about it :->